# OperationFailure: Authentication failed when inserting into a MongoDB collection despite correct credentials

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb

I have a MongoDB database and I try to add things things in it from a colaboratory notebook:

```
client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb+srv://test:<mypassjeje>@<unique identifier>.mongodb.net/<dbnamejojo>?retryWrites=true&w=majority")
db = client.test
fragrance = db.fragrance_db
```

I replaced  with the password for the test user and  with the name of the database that the connections will use by default.

Pero cuando intento insertar una cosa:

```
fragrance.insert_one(perfume)
```

It returns:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OperationFailure                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-48-d831294ab74e> in <module>()
     46         count += 1
     47 
---> 48 __main__()

19 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pymongo/helpers.py in _check_command_response(response, max_wire_version, msg, allowable_errors, parse_write_concern_error)
    166             msg = msg or "%s"
    167             raise OperationFailure(msg % errmsg, code, response,
--> 168                                    max_wire_version)
    169 
    170 

OperationFailure: bad auth : Authentication failed., full error: {'ok': 0, 'errmsg': 'bad auth : Authentication failed.', 'code': 8000, 'codeName': 'AtlasError'}
```

I also try with `&authSource=admin` at the end:

```
client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb+srv://test:<mypassjeje>@<unique identifier>.mongodb.net/<dbnamejojo>?retryWrites=true&w=majority&authSource=admin")
```

but it returns the same error:

```
OperationFailure: bad auth : Authentication failed., full error: {'ok': 0, 'errmsg': 'bad auth : Authentication failed.', 'code': 8000, 'codeName': 'AtlasError'}
```

Comment: Append `&authSource=admin` on the string. `cluster0.x8uid` is a unique identifier for your cluster, I wouldn't include it in a post. Not very important though.

Comment: @Minsky Thanks for your comment and advise. I modified my code. Nevertheless I still get the same error ...

Comment: Check that the password is correct and try the non-srv uri.

Comment: Another (rare) cause could be that the user was created with a different auth database. But keep it in mind if @D.SM does not work. If you know who created the user, ask. If it's default user the user is `m001-student`, the pass `m001-mongodb-basics` and is registered in `admin` XD.  If nothing seems to work, it could be the IP whitelist under network (or security) config in Atlas. You can write `0.0.0.0/0` as a first try (change it later).